# SSMS and SQLCMD displays only the first 8000 characters

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms, sqlcmd

In SSMS when I try to execute:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), REPLICATE('a',9000))
```

I see only the first 8000 characters displayed. The settings **Tool >> Options >> Query Results >> Sql Server >> Results to Grid** is set to 65534 and **Results to Text** is set to 8192.

Also when I try to run this from **SQLCMD**

```
sqlcmd -S Server -E -y 0 -Q "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), REPLICATE('a',9000))" -o out.txt
```

I see only 8000 charecters.

The flag **-y 0** is supposed to set it up to 1 MB. But I do not more than 8000 characters.

What could be the problem?

thanks,
_UB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[REPLICATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx) output is based on the datatype input. So this explains sqlcmd.

> If string expression is not of type varchar(max) or nvarchar(max),
>   REPLICATE truncates the return value
>   at 8,000 bytes. To return values
>   greater than 8,000 bytes,
>   string expression must be explicitly
>   cast to the appropriate large-value
>   data type.

So, use this `SELECT REPLICATE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 'a'), 9000)`

And SSMS has never shown all text data (nor did Query Analyzer)

Comment: ahh... REPLICATE. I knew that. Just did not think of it before posting. My bad.

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

See here :

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/varchar(max)/67057/

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR(MAX) is only capable of holding 8000 characters

[see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

From MSDN:

> varchar [ ( n | max ) ] -
>   Variable-length, non-Unicode character
>   data. n can be a value from 1 through
>   8,000. max indicates that the maximum
>   storage size is 2^31-1 bytes

As Joseph (below) says, to hold more, use a text or ntext data type, but if you want to be able to search that, then you'd need some form of full-text indexing enabled.

[Better Link](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/da-db_1.htm)

Comment: varchar(max) is a LOB type! Your quote actually says "max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes"

Comment: my appologies on the poorlink, see here http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/da-db_1.htm for a full layout. Also, that's storage size, not max characters.

Comment: Even worse: the new link is for SQL 7 which did not have varchar(max) which *replaces text datatype*

Comment: really ? I remember storing more than 8000 characters in VARCHAR(MAX) before. As far as I know, it can store up to 2 GB data.

Comment: From BoL:
max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes